# Find Values not in Table from SPLIT_STRING

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, split, sql-server-2016

I have a procedure that will find all of the records in a table based upon if they are in a comma-separated string.

```
DECLARE @PMIDList NVARCHAR(max) = '31282781,31226541,30518502,30262330,30154192,29781323,29222269,28516439,28314698,27130328,26031546,25963431'

SELECT PMID 
FROM ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members 
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@PMIDList,',') ON value = dbo.ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members.PMID
```

However I want to turn that around a bit and find the values that are in the comma separated string that are NOT in the table.

I added

```
SELECT PMID 
FROM ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members 
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@PMIDList,',') ON value = dbo.ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members.PMID
WHERE ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members.PMID IS NULL
```

But how can I get the comma string value to show up as the value?  Do I need to put all of the values into a tmp table and then do a joint to find the NULL records?  I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thanks guys- How the heck can I pick a best answer when they all do what I need but just a little bit differently.  Each one of you fellows really helped me out.  THANK YOU.  I will play with all three over night.

Comment: You can honor of all them with an up-vote. And you can pick the one which performs best. Or the *fastest gun in the west* (I think this was Ed Bangga). Or the one you like most... That is completely up to you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your query

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT t1.value, PMID 
 FROM  STRING_SPLIT(@PMIDList,',') t1
 LEFT JOIN ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members ON value = dbo.ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members.PMID
) t2 WHERE t2.PMID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the values which exist on comma separated values but not on table you can get the data in this way.

```
select '31282781' as ID into #temp union all 
select '31226541' as ID union all 
select '30518502' as ID union all 
select '30262330' as ID  

DECLARE @PMIDList NVARCHAR(max) = '31282781,31226541,30518502,30262330,30154192,29781323,29222269,28516439,28314698,27130328,26031546,25963431'

SELECT  value as CSVdata   
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@PMIDList,',') t2 
left join #temp t  on t2.value = t.ID 
where t.ID is null
```

Output:

```
 CSVdata
30154192
29781323
29222269
28516439
28314698
27130328
26031546
25963431
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use NOT EXISTS ()

```
SELECT *
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@PMIDList,',') v
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   ADMIN_API_Pubs_Members x
           WHERE  x.PMID  = v.VALUE
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called an anti-Join. For Anti-joins you use `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT`. Note the sample data below (I excluded the last three items in the string from @yourtable).

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (PMID BIGINT);
INSERT @yourtable VALUES (31282781),(31226541),(30518502),(30262330),(30154192),
                         (29781323),(29222269),(28516439),(28314698);    

-- Sample List
DECLARE @PMIDList NVARCHAR(max) = 
  '31282781,31226541,30518502,30262330,30154192,29781323,29222269,28516439,28314698,27130328,26031546,25963431';

-- Solution #1 using EXCEPT
SELECT s.[value] FROM string_split(@PMIDList,',') AS s
EXCEPT 
SELECT t.PMID    FROM @yourtable AS t;

-- Solution #2 using NOT IN
SELECT s.[value]
FROM   string_split(@PMIDList,',') AS s
WHERE  s.[value] NOT IN (SELECT t.PMID FROM @yourtable AS t);
```

Each solution return rows that only exist in the string. EXCEPT is more succinct and will remove duplicates, NOT IN will not remove duplicates . Removing duplicates requires a sort; if you don't need to worry about duplicates then NOT IN (or NOT EXISTS) will be more efficient.